# Angular Material SlideToggle Not Sliding

Tags: angular, angular-material, slidetoggle

I have an Angular component ("new-form"), which has a slide toggle from [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview). The slide toggle renders on the client, but nothing happens when I click on it.

I've installed angular material, and it exists in my package.json (^17.0.4). Please explain why the slide toggle is not working.

Here is **new-form.component.html**:

```
<mat-slide-toggle>Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
```

And, here is **new-form.component.ts**:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-form',
  templateUrl: 'new-form.component.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatSlideToggleModule],
})
export class NewFormComponent {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed adding the CSS in `global-styles.css`

```
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fc5jtq)

Comment: I don't have a "global-styles.css" file in my current file structure... I have an "app.component.css" file..?

Comment: @newby73 Please import there as a last resort, you can also check if there is a common css file for the entire project, by going to `angular.json` and checking the styles array! usually angular projects have a common css file!

Comment: Okay, I added the global css file with the import (and updated "styles" in angular.json), but the toggle still does not slide when clicked...

Comment: @newby73 Could you replicate the issue you are facing on the stackblitz provided and share back?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in my `index.html` file. I wasn't using the correct syntax to render the root component. Specifically, I was rendering the component using a trailing forward slash:

```
<app-root/>
```

When I should have used the traditional way of defining a component:

```
<app-root></app-root>
```